# How to know if a USB-C dock will power a laptop via PD?

Tags: laptop, usb

I have a Dell Vostro 7500 that, according to Dell's site, supports Power Delivery via USB-C.  I have been looking at docking stations and most of them are 65W or 100W via USB-C.  Looking at the PD spec it looks like 100W is max?  The power brick that comes with the Vostro seems to be 130W.  Does that mean the Dock has to push out 130W?  If that's the case, maybe I'm looking at an older spec for PD?

Comment: Not entirely sure, that's why this is a comment, not an answer. I suspect the 130watt is to be able to take heavy loads, such as while gaming. If that is the case a 100W dock should still charge the battery if you are not doing power intensive tasks and if you do, should drain the battery slower.

Comment: As I research this I am seeing the same thing over and over.  It looks like the Dell dock can up itself to 130w [for a laptop like yours](https://www.dell.com/community/Vostro/Charging-Vostro-7500-through-USB-C/td-p/7802522).  It also looks like many other people have had the same exact problem of not getting a charge on a lesser wattage.  It seems to depend on the model as many people say that it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Looking at the PD spec it looks like 100W is max? The power brick that
> comes with the Vostro seems to be 130W. Does that mean the Dock has to
> push out 130W?

No, it does not mean the dock has to "push out" 130W. Power Delivery over Type-C connector is a highly flexible technology. Your laptop has great flexibility in managing its internal power consumption, including display brightness, and will throttle CPU in accord with available power, be it external and/or battery. Your laptop will be perfectly aware of the dock (power provider) capability through PD messading protocol, and the system management software will limit laptop's consumption up to the negotiated capability. When using dock for power, you might have a little less performance on extreme power-demanding apps, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your question is. To properly charge a device over PD, you need to know the specs of the device and the specs of the charger.

What is the recommended wattage for charging the laptop? It came with a 130W brick, but I do not think that full wattage is needed to power the Dell. Likely you do not need that much wattage- but you need to search for this on the Dell site/Dell support.

If you are using a charger with lower wattage, it will charge but at a slower rate. If it charges less than power consumption, it will drain faster than it charges.